# C#.NET: DataTable Retrieve Column After Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I would like to response.write the value of the field "requestDate" after it gets inserted into my database.  I have a "select requestDate..." statement after I do the SQL insert, but I can't seem to get the web page to see it.

I have tried: `Response.Write(dt.Rows[0]["requestDate"].ToString());`, but I get an error that states "requestDate" doesn't belong to the table.  requestDate isn't one of my parameters, but was hoping the select I did after the insert would allow me to use it.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

dataAccess.cs:

```
public static SqlConnection DEV
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEV"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }

public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName, SqlConnection connection, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection);
        DataSet returnSet = new DataSet();
        if (sqlParams != null)
            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(returnSet);
        connection.Close();
        if (returnSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            return returnSet.Tables[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Code Behind page doing the insert:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = dataAccess.ExecuteDataTable
                (
                    "spInsert", dataAccess.DEV, new SqlParameter[2]
                    {
                        new SqlParameter ("@vRecID", hidIDs.Value),
                        new SqlParameter ("@vTransDate", txtTransDate.Text)     
                    }
                );

                Response.Write(dt.Rows[0]["requestDate"].ToString());
```

Markup page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat = "server" ID = "hidIDs" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTransDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

SQL:

```
Insert Into Requests
    ( 
        transDate,  
        requestDate
    )

    Values 
    (
        @vTransDate, 
        getDate()
    )
    Select recID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

    Select requestDate from Requests
    Where recID = @vRecID
```

Comment: I can't see any bug in your code at first sight. Have you tried to debug? Is there any table in the dataset, is there any rows in first table? Has the columns correct name? I would try to use some ORM for this purpose, maybe an entity framework. What you want to achieve is would be more simple with that way.

Comment: I have debugged, and I can do a response.write of the record ID that is being inserted, but not the requestDate field.  And when I run the SP in SQL, it works just fine and performs the select.  My guess is it has something to do with the fact that the requestDate isn't a parameter?  I edited my post to show where I am trying to do the repsonse.write.  The debug error is simply "requestDate is not a column in the table."  I am not certain what ORM is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"RequestDate isn't a parameter", that is not a problem. You are returning a result of a select which contains the requestDate column, so it should be in your datatable. I haven't tried to reproduce your code, so I don't know what is the bug, but what you are trying to do is an outdated way of accessing data, leastwise complicated.

ORM is object releation mapping. A simple Strongly-typed ADO.net Dataset could be also good (It generates yor returning entity). So there is 2 simple way of projecting your SQL result in c#.

[ADO.Net strongly-typed dataset](http://youtu.be/fTPc9bCZrnY?t=11m21s)

And here is an Entity Framework tutorial (This is an ORM):

[Introduction to Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)

Comment: I opted for strongly-typed dataset.  Very good tutorial.  Will read up on ORM as I have time.  Thanks!

Comment: No probs, the key feautre of ORM, it projects you releations, if you have foreign key in database, eg. table A refers to Table B then you can reach all releated recods via a simple property of table A in code behind. In other words, you don't have to write joins in code behind if you had foreign key reference. You can use linq to entities and linq to entities queries are translated to SQL.

Comment: Take a look at this to getting familiar with linq to entites: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features

Answer (score 0):

Can you try returning "returnSet.Tables[1]" (the next table) instead of "returnSet.Tables[0]".
Your SQL has two select statements, the data-adapter could be filling the dataset with two tables.